# Return an IEnumerable<MyDTO> in an extra Response wrapper class

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dto, data-transfer-objects

Should my service return a collection of DTO`s or should a class with the postfix "Response" wrap my dto collection and return it?

I am confused by too many different samples and whats the advantage of it approach.

```
public class LessonPlannerResponse
{
   public IEnumerable<PeriodDTO> Periods { get; set; }   
}
```

As I do a Single Page Application with less business logic but much UI logic there will not be many DTO`s and not much reason to alter/extend it.

Comment: I suggest always using a wrapper when passing a collection out to the WS layer. It makes the DTO easier to extend or alter without breaking the existing contract(s). Also, not all WS layers can deal [well] with raw collections.

Comment: thanks I will do as you suggested.